# Java EE - Entity management in GUI

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, managed-bean, jta

I'm using JPA with JTA in a Java EE enterprise application including an ejb and a web module that includes the managed beans related to the web pages.

The managed beans should be able to retrieve entities from the database passing through methods offered by my ejbs.

I have a User entity representing the data of the users registered in the system, and I want to allow the user to modify his email, his password and some other settings.

For instance let's consider this entity (abstracted from all the factors that doesn't have influence here):

```
@Entity
public class User {
..........
    private string email;
    *getter and setter for email*
    private string city;
    *getter and setter for city*
..........
}
```

In my web module I have xhtml files referencing Managed beans via Expression Language.

for instance I may have in Index.xhtml

```
<someEditableTag>#{myBean.user.email}</someEditableTag>
<someEditableTag>#{myBean.user.city}</someEditableTag>
<someButton>#{myBean.user.confirm()}</someButton>
```

In my bean then:

```
@Managed
@RequestScoped
public class myBean {
..........
   private user;
   public getUser() {
     if(user == null)
       user = someEJB.getLoggedUser(); // Retrieve from DB the user entity associated to logged user
     return user;
   }
   public void confirm() {
   // Call some ejb method to update the settings of the user in the database with the new data on the page
   }
..........
}
```

My issue is that if the editable fields refer to my entity in the persistence context, shouldn't this already in some manner trigger an update when I edit the data on the page? Not exactly while I'm writing the data, but the edited data reference my entity via Expression Language in the xhtml.

In short, I'm afraid that the managed bean could modify the entity in the database just by accessing the setters of the entity I return from my ejb if the changes in the managed entity are committed automatically and not by using my confirm function that calls some ejb's method.

There's a lot I don't know about these tools so I'd like to have your opinion on this doubt I just mentioned.

I thought about some solutions, like for instance detaching the entities in the ejbs before passing them to the managed beans but that doesn't seem like a good solution. I'd like to know what is the standard design pattern for this kind of issues. Any example of solution would work fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you wont execute `merge` or `insert` metohod from [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) on your entity, nothing should happen in DB. You can always refresh your entity with [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html). However, if you are affraid to use entity in your web tire, you can always use DTO pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check if the DTO pattern suits my purposes. As for the first part of your answer, why should that work that way? I mean, in one of my tests I had one my managed beans called a method of a stateless ejb that uses the setter of a managed entity already in the db without calling a merge from the EntityManager. As soon as the ejb's method terminates the changes are actually committed to the database. Does this mean that for a Stateless bean the entity changes are automatically committed but not for a Managed,RequestScoped one?

Comment: Im not an expoert, but i think invoking settter of entity in JSF ManagedBean and EJB bean is a different issue. They EJB runs in dirrerent Container then Managed JSF bean. Every operation in EJB,if nothing special happens like RuntimeException,  (as far as your transaction manager in persistance.xml is set to JTA) ends with commit to DB. However, JSF ManagedBean dosen't have this behavior.

Comment: Perfect, this would actually solve my issue I suppose. Do you have any link where I can read about these behaviours? Thanks for the help

Comment: Dont have any specific links, but read about EJB Container (for example in Wiki). Also you can start with this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnabo.html

Comment: I actually was reading that right now, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: By the way, a consequence of relying on this fact (thus allowing the managed beans to access the setters of my managed entities) means that each time I need to use my entities (potentially modified by the managed beans even if the change wasn't committed) I need to refresh them to prevent those changes from leaking in. Is that right?

Comment: What do you mean by leaking in?

Comment: I'll describe an example. Let's say that some managed bean performs some changes on a managed entity retrieved using an ejb's method. Those changes are performed by using the entity's setters, but no merge happens so they aren't committed. Anyway the entity in the persistence context should still have the edited data if no refresh is performed. After a while another ejb method gets called. This method edits and saves some fields of that entity that we previously modified. If no refresh is done before this, the entity saved will have also the data edited by the managed bean. Is that right?

Comment: yeah, i understand that your point is that as soon as changed entity will get into ejb, its changes will get commitet? I dont know if it will happen (since the change did not happen in ejb, but you have to check it for your self), but i dont thnk you sholud pass to ejb changed entity if you dont want to update it. Usually you should have ejb methods like changeSomeProperty with id to entity you want to change and value to be changed. Maybe this article can be of some help: http://palkonyves.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-design-clean-business-tier-with.html

Comment: The article was really helpful in conjunction with the things you previously explained. I did some testing and I can confirm that when the managed bean retrieves using the ejb's method an entity from the persistence context that entity actually isn't managed at all anymore. I suppose the detach happens right when the entity exits the ejb container. This totally solves my potential issues. Thanks a lot for your help, it was extremely useful!